# Webform - How to filter submissions by user?

Tags: views, webforms

I need to make a view that displays to the current user her own submissions.

Option 1: For a specific node and then I can display also the data.
Option 2: For any node and then I can just use the metadata of the submission.

Could not find how to do it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the view to display the webform submissions. You need to give the webform node id to fetch particular submissions.

I have added the exported view. This is just displaying the submitter name as per my webform. So this is just skeletal view. You can add fields as per your requirement. You will have to change your webform node id and manipulate as per your requirement.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'webform_submission';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'webform_submissions';
$view->human_name = 'Webform Submission';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Webform submissions: Serial number */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['serial']['id'] = 'serial';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['serial']['table'] = 'webform_submissions';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['serial']['field'] = 'serial';
/* Field: Webform submission data: Value */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['id'] = 'value';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['table'] = 'webform_submissions';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['field'] = 'value';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['webform_nid'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['value']['webform_cid'] = '1';
/* Contextual filter: Content: Author uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'user/webform_submissions';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplished this task by downloading this module https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views

After that, you can get all the elements from your webforms in the VIEWS. Works for me.